# Validating Data in Storm Topology

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm, bigdata

We have a hadoop cluster in google cloud and we are expecting 2TB of data per day. The architecture involves storm->HDFS->Hive.

Now I don't have that much of info on storm so can anyone please let me know from testing stand point that if I'm receiving JSON data in storm, is there any way I can validate the data to make sure the data sent from source and the data received in Storm topology are correct or i can test the data only when its available in HDFS.

As I have researched I can find only unit testing for bolts in storm. Is this the only way to test the data.

Comment: Storm doesn't know anything about your data. This is your main goal to provide for Storm more information if you want to validate sent and received messages. If it possible you can include in your JSON message a checksum field for critical data. In this case Storm will calculate the checksum for received message and compare this value with a value received in the checksum field.

Comment: Thanks for the info @llya Lapitan